# How to add N’userId’ to insert into SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, mybatis

I'm using mybatis with SQL Server. When I insert some query, I want to use

```
N'something to insert'
```

in the mybatis query.

For example, I tried

```
N'#{userId}'
```

but it generated an error..

How can I do this?

Comment: The `N'..'` notation in SQL Server just denotes an **Unicode** string literal (as opposed to a non-Unicode string literal, if you omit the `N` before the single quotes). Not sure what you're expecting here ....

Comment: what i want to know is how to add prefix N in mybatis query. for example.. insert into test values(N’userId’).. i want to change this query statement into mybatis query statement

Comment: have you try without N? example: #{userId}

Answer (score 0):

I guess it works when you pass hard-coded value:

```
N'userId'
```

If you pass the literal value with:

```
N'${userId}'
```

it should behave the same way, the value will appear is the generated SQL:

```
INSERT INTO test VALUES(N'userId')
```

It do not know if error you are facing is due to the fact that N notation does not support bind parameters, generated SQL is:

```
INSERT INTO test VALUES(N'?')
```

Or maybe you just need remove quotes because the parameter is already a string/varchar:

```
N#{userId}
```